# Parse output of 'ip addr' via Python

Tags: python, regex, parsing, python-2.7

I need some help parsing the output of the  `ip addr` command as dumped to a text file, with contents like this:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN \    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
1: lo    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
1: lo    inet6 ::1/128 scope host \       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: em1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bond0 state UP qlen 1000\    link/ether b8:ca:3a:65:43:3c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: em2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bond0 state UP qlen 1000\    link/ether b8:ca:3a:65:43:3c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: em3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bond1 state UP qlen 1000\    link/ether b8:ca:3a:65:43:3e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: em4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bond1 state UP qlen 1000\    link/ether b8:ca:3a:65:43:3e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: p1p1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 1000\    link/ether a0:36:9f:27:13:48 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: p1p2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 1000\    link/ether a0:36:9f:27:13:49 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
8: p1p3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 1000\    link/ether a0:36:9f:27:13:4a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
9: p1p4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 1000\    link/ether a0:36:9f:27:13:4b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
10: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP \    link/ether b8:ca:3a:65:43:3c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
10: bond0    inet6 fe80::baca:3aff:fe65:433c/64 scope link \       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
12: bond1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP \    link/ether b8:ca:3a:65:43:3e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
12: bond1    inet6 fe80::baca:3aff:fe65:433e/64 scope link \       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

As you can see, there will be lines that start similarly (^\d: $device), and I'm at a loss of how to be able to iterate over the file, and pull out select information (ipv4 addr, ipv6 addr if present, link state, hw addr) for each device when this information is spread over multiple lines.

Suggestions?

Comment: hint: the data appear to be in the form of `device_number`, `device_name`, `<angle-bracketed stuff>`, `field1_name`, `field1_value`, `field2_name`, `field2_value`, etc... All separated by spaces.

Comment: A two pass solution: Could probably start by collecting all the same lines `^(\d+:).*$(?:\s*^\1.*$)*` using Multi-line mode. Then other regex's to parse each sub-line.

Comment: FYI, the output will be easier to parse if you use `ip -o addr list`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from itertools import groupby

interfaces = {}
with open('ip.txt') as f:
    lines = [line for line in f if line.strip()]
    # group by line number
    for key, group in groupby(lines, lambda x: x.split()[0]):
        interface = []
        for thing in group:
            # append lines without repeating part
            interface += thing.split()[2:]
        if interface:
            interfaces[key] = interface

    for key, interface in interfaces.items():
        for x in ['inet', 'inet6', 'state', 'link/ether']:
            if x in interface:
                idx = interface.index(x)
                print '%s %s=%s' % (key, x, interface[idx+1])


$ python ip.py
3: state=UP
3: link/ether=b8:ca:3a:65:43:3c
4: state=UP
4: link/ether=b8:ca:3a:65:43:3e
5: state=UP
5: link/ether=b8:ca:3a:65:43:3e
1: inet=127.0.0.1/8
1: inet6=::1/128
1: state=UNKNOWN
10: inet6=fe80::baca:3aff:fe65:433c/64
10: state=UP
10: link/ether=b8:ca:3a:65:43:3c
2: state=UP
2: link/ether=b8:ca:3a:65:43:3c
8: state=DOWN
8: link/ether=a0:36:9f:27:13:4a
9: state=DOWN
9: link/ether=a0:36:9f:27:13:4b
12: inet6=fe80::baca:3aff:fe65:433e/64
12: state=UP
12: link/ether=b8:ca:3a:65:43:3e
6: state=DOWN
6: link/ether=a0:36:9f:27:13:48
7: state=DOWN
7: link/ether=a0:36:9f:27:13:49
```